# unexpected GC behaviour

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, windows-phone-8, arrays

I'm seeing some strange GC behaviour on the WP8 emulator when working with large byte arrays, i.e. the memory is not released, nor reused.

Example: 
The memory usage baseline of my application is ~17MB. If I then allocate a 50MB byte array memory usage will as expected increase to 67MB. I reinitialize the byte array to a size of zero and call GC.Collect() which doesn't reduce the total memory usage. This is as expected; the memory aren't release back to windows, merely flagged as reusable. 
If I then reinitialize the byte array to the same size, 50MB, I would expect the memory to be reused and the total memory usage not to increase. Right? False. Memory is not reused and now the total memory usage is 117 MB. See sample code below..

Can anyone explain this? Since I'm allocating the exact same number of bytes the problem shouldn't be rooted in LOH fragmentation, right?

```
    // memory usage = 17MB
    var tb = new byte[1024*1024*50];
    // memory usage = 67MB
    tb = new byte[0];
    GC.Collect();
    // memory usage = 67MB
    tb = null;
    GC.Collect();
    // memory usage = 67MB
    tb = new byte[1024*1024*50];
    // memory usage = 117MB
    GC.Collect();
    // memory usage = 117MB;
```

Comment: How do you measure the memory usage?

Comment: So what's the problem? You're using 117 MB of the 2000 MB of virtual address space you have available. If that starts running low, worry then. The GC is good at managing memory; let it do its job.

Comment: @Eric, My problem is that I'm running on a WP8 device/emulator. I don't have the luxury of 2GB virtual address space... The environment throws OutOfMemoryException as I hit ~250MB och RAM usage. The 117MB sample code was an _example_.

Comment: Ah, I missed the bit about the emulator. Is the problem that you're not getting a collection when you expect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with a button to repeat the allocation, the first click more or less acts like you describe but after that the memory use is flat.

So your observations are most likely disturbed by start-up issues and maybe allocations happening in the background.

The GC, from a broader perspective, behaves as expected.

Comment: My app is - in its current state - single threaded so I know for sure that I'm not doing any allocations in the background. "start-up" issues seems a bit vague and it's not something I would put my money on since the scenario is reproducable regardless the time the app has been running. Never the less, I guess the GC behaves the way it's supposed to and I'll just have to resort good ol' c++ and manual memory mgmt instead.

Comment: _I'll just have to resort ..._ No, I think you should read Eric's comment and take it to heart. I still think your main conclusion, _Memory is not reused and ...._ is off. Make sure you're not hunting a ghost.

Comment: I'm using the built-in profiler in VS2012 to measure memory usage. Eric's comment is off as he assumes I'm on a desktop environment where memory is _cheap_. Unfortunately, I'm neither "off" or "hunting a ghost". Memory is not reused properly which, on a desktop environment, is not an issue. I successfully implemented my app in native code instead using malloc/free for memory allocation/deallocation.

Comment: I also ran some similar (but not identical) code in the emulator. No problems, certainly nothing supporting your claim. So I still think it's a measuring artifact.